# Adding Pagination to Member Directory in WordPress with JetEngine and Elementor

Tags: wordpress, pagination, elementor, jet-engine

I've created a member directory using JetEngine and Elementor in WordPress, and I'm having trouble implementing pagination for the directory. I've tried the following steps, but pagination still doesn't work:

1. Created a query using JetEngine's Query Builder.
2. Configured pagination options within the query.
3. Ensured my WordPress theme is compatible with JetEngine and Elementor.

However, no pagination is displayed on the directory. I also tried using various pagination plugins, but they didn't resolve the issue either.

I'm looking for guidance on how to properly set up pagination for this member directory. Any help or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated.

- WordPress Version: [6.3.2]
- JetEngine Version: [3.2.5]
- Elementor Version: [3.16.4]

Please let me know if there are additional details or code samples needed to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.